# Using a dictionary to plot graph in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dictionary of the form:

```
[('2019-10', 273), ('2019-11', 299), ('2019-12', 244), ('2020-01', 231), ('2020-02', 232)]
```

I want to plot this dictionary as a graph, with the dates as the x axis and the corresponding values as the bars. How can I achieve this? I am new to D3, hence have very little knowledge of it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi Devang. I am unable to think of how I should proceed. Any tips? As of now I have only worked with lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data is in the format:

```
[{'2019-10': 273}, {'2019-11': 299}, {'2019-12': 244}, {'2020-01': 231}, {'2020-02': 232}]
```

You could first apply some mapping function to transform this into a more convenient format and go from there, e.g.:

```js
var height = 200;
var width = 400;

var data = [{'2019-10': 273}, {'2019-11': 299}, {'2019-12': 244}, {'2020-01': 231}, {'2020-02': 232}];

var mapped = data.map(d => {
  return {
    date: Object.keys(d)[0],
    count: d[Object.keys(d)[0]]
  }
});

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

x.domain(mapped.map(d => d.date));
y.domain([0, d3.max(mapped, d => d.count)]);
  
var svg = d3.select("#simple").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll("bar")
    .data(mapped)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", d => x(d.date))
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", d => y(d.count))
      .attr("height", d => height - y(d.count));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="simple"></div>
```